# Can't delete file named '...'

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, filesystems

For some background, I'm on Windows 10 however with the files I'm going to talk about I've used them in shared folders with Ubuntu VMs before.

In a folder on my machine, there is a file named '...'
I really don't know where this file came from. It was inside a directory which contained one of my programming projects, in which I was using git. However, I cannot delete this file in any means I've tried so far. When attempting a simple right-click + delete, I get the message: "Error 0x80070091 The directory is not empty."

When I attempt to delete from powershell using del or rm, I get the message: "When attempting to del : An object at the specified path C:\Users\mdmil\Concurrency\... does not exist."

I cannot rename the file by any means. When I try to rename from powershell, I get the same aforementioned error. When I try to rename from file explorer, I get a "this file is open in another program" error.

I even got desparate enough to try to share the folder with a Linux VM, and attempt to delete the file via the inode number to no avail.

When I attempt to open the file in notepad++, no file opens. I presume it is because it is trying to interpret it as a directory due to the ... naming.

I'm currently at a loss as to how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the directory where the `...` file is, then type:

```
type dir /x
```

you should see the file and its 8.3 name, eg:-

```
 Directory of C:\Users\CurrentUser\Temp

09/12/2018  23:09    <DIR>                       .
09/12/2018  23:09    <DIR>                       ..
09/12/2018  23:09                 0 A535~1       ...
```

You can now use this 8.3 name to delete it, eg:

```
del A535~1
```

Comment: AFH, I am out-of-town and utilizing my phone right now, but I am rather certain that this question (and your proposed answer) have been posted in a prominent Super User Q&A previously. You are one of our community’s very best contributors, so perhaps you can point the OP in that direction. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Run5k - I searched and found this 9-year-old [answer](https://superuser.com/a/76830/327367), which is the same as mine, though it's not the accepted answer, and there weren't a lot of votes for either the question (7) or the answer (2) - I've not found anything more prominent. The question is related, but not quite the same, so I don't know if it qualifies as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I made it back to my hotel late last night and found two Super User questions within my list of Favorites that should qualify as duplicates.  I posted them under the question accordingly.

Comment: I've checked your links, and the `\\?\` prefix also works, making it a very good alternative solution. I think readers should be aware of both solutions, as there may be certain circumstances when only one of them works.

Comment: From my perspective, the bottom line is as follows:  [this question](https://superuser.com/q/53281/650163) is essentially the same problem, and [this subsequent answer](https://superuser.com/a/53306/650163) is the equivalent of yours.  You really can't have too many good options within the Super User realm, but I hate to see a brand-new contributor (like the OP) creating what is essentially a duplicate of a Q&A with over 2000 views, an accepted answer, and numerous up-votes.

Comment: @Run5k - Fair comment. That answer is a lot more prominent, having gained a lot more votes (17) than the one I found, though it's not the accepted answer (`\\?\ prefix`), which has fewer votes. The question text is also closer. Unfortunately I did not find this question in my searches - I used both the SU search box and Google with `site:superuser.com`.

Comment: You were obviously quite thorough, and all of us will occasionally "miss one" when it comes to posting a duplicate answer.  I have actually had the mods accidentally do it to me before!  ;-)  Once again, thanks for the feedback *and* your great contributions, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix to the issue. It's not a great solution, but it worked. I opened git bash to that folder, use "rm -rf ..." and that deleted the file in question. Still haven't figured out how to fix it with native Windows tools.

Comment: If you type `dir /x` in the directory where the `...` file is, then you should see its 8.3 name, and you should be able to use this to delete it. I can't create this file, so I can't be completely sure that this works.

Comment: I have used `bash` to create `...` and can verify that the method works, so I have submitted an answer for the benefit of others, especially those who don't have `bash`.